# How to reduce the number of independent variables in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am not srue whether this is really a mathematical question, or actually a mathematica question. :D

suppose I have a matrix

```
{{4/13 + (9 w11)/13 + (6 w12)/13, 
  6/13 + (9 w21)/13 + (6 w22)/13}, {-(6/13) + (6 w11)/13 + (4 w12)/
   13, -(9/13) + (6 w21)/13 + (4 w22)/13}}
```

with `w11`, `w12`, `w21`, `w22` as free parameters.

And I know by visual inspection that `3*w11+2*w12` can be represented as one variable, and `3*w21+2*w22` can be represented as another. So essentially this matrix only has two independent variables. Given any matrix of this form, is there any method to automatically reduce the number of independent variables? I guess I am stuck at formulating this in a precise mathematical way.

Please share your thoughts. Many thanks.

**Edit:**

My question is really the following.
Given matrix like this

```
{{4/13 + (9 w11)/13 + (6 w12)/13, 
  6/13 + (9 w21)/13 + (6 w22)/13}, {-(6/13) + (6 w11)/13 + (4 w12)/
   13, -(9/13) + (6 w21)/13 + (4 w22)/13}}
```

or involving some other symbolical constants

```
{{a+4/13 + (9 w11)/13 + (6 w12)/13, 
  6/13*c + (9 w21)/13 + (6 w22)/13}, {-(6/13)/d + (6 w11)/13 + (4 w12)/
   13, -(9/13) + (6 w21)/13 + (4 w22)/13}}
```

I want to use mathematica to automatically identify the number `n` of independent variables (in this case is 2), and then name these independent varirables y1, y2, ..., yn, and then re-write the matrix in terms of y1, y2, ..., yn instead of w11, w12, w21, w22.

Comment: Without trying to be purist, you need _equations_ to solve for variables. You only have some sums there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Starting with

```
mat = {{4/13 + (9 w11)/13 + (6 w12)/13,6/13 + (9 w21)/13 + (6 w22)/13},
  {-(6/13) + (6 w11)/13 + (4 w12)/13, -(9/13) + (6 w21)/13 + (4 w22)/13}};
```

Form a second matrix, of indeterminates, same dimensions.

```
mat2 = Array[y, Dimensions[mat]];
```

Now consider the polynomial (actually linear) system formed by setting mat-mat2==0. We can eliminate the original variables and look for dependencies amongst the new ones. Could use Eliminate; I'll show with GroebnerBasis.

```
GroebnerBasis[Flatten[mat - mat2], Variables[mat2], Variables[mat]]
```

Out[59]= {-3 + 2 y[1, 2] - 3 y[2, 2], -2 + 2 y[1, 1] - 3 y[2, 1]}

So we get a pair of explicit relations between the original matrix elements.

---edit---

You can get expressions for the new variables that clearly indicates the dependency of two of them on the other two. To do this, form the Groebner basis and use it in polynomial reduction.

```
gb = GroebnerBasis[Flatten[mat - mat2], Variables[mat2], Variables[mat]];
vars = Flatten[mat2];

PolynomialReduce[vars, gb, vars][[All, 2]]
```

Out[278]= {1 + 3/2 y[2, 1], 3/2 + 3/2 y[2, 2], y[2, 1], y[2, 2]}

---end edit---

Daniel Lichtblau
Wolfram Research

Comment: +1, definitely the simplest solution. Incidentally, unlike in his previous question, `CoefficientArrays` does not work here as it treats each row of the matrix separately, and not as a vector of variables dotted with a vector of matrices which I've had trouble with in the past. Also, I have to look at `GroebnerBasis` again, as I never know when, or how, it is applicable.

Comment: @Daniel, thanks a lot. After getting this `{-3 + 2 y[1, 2] - 3 y[2, 2], -2 + 2 y[1, 1] - 3 y[2, 1]}`, how to use it? Does this tell me the redundant degree of freedom is 2? If so, for example, I am given two (because 4-2=2!) new variables y1, y2 and I want to re-write the original matrix `{{4/13 + (9 w11)/13 + (6 w12)/13, 
  6/13 + (9 w21)/13 + (6 w22)/13}, {-(6/13) + (6 w11)/13 + (4 w12)/
   13, -(9/13) + (6 w21)/13 + (4 w22)/13}}` in terms of y1 and y2 rather than w11, w12, w21, w22, how can this be done?

Comment: @rcollyer: i am not sure what you meant by the "unlike in his previous question, CoefficientArrays does not work here as it treats each row of the matrix separately" comment. How CoefficientArrays can be related here?

Comment: @Daniel, also this does not seem to work if I have another constant, for example, `a`,  involved in the matrix, for example `{-3*a + 2 y[1, 2] - 3 y[2, 2], -2 + 2 y[1, 1] - 3 y[2, 1]}`, as now, Variables[mat] changes to `{a,w11, w12, w21, w22}`. Thanks.

Comment: @Qiang Li You will need to edit your question so I can see specifically how you bring the new variable into the matrix. What you show has it in the Groebner basis, but I do not know the input you used.

Comment: @Qiang Li As for rewriting the original matrix, remember we set mat equal to mat2, so you know for example that y[1,1] is equal to mat[[1,1]]. The Groebner basis then tells you how some y's are related, so you can replace e.g. y[2, 1] by (-2 + 2 y[1, 1])/(-3). The programmatic way to do this would use PolynomialReduce. I am reluctant to edit the response just yet, until I see what exactly is the question (now) under consideration.

Comment: @Qiang Li, the matrix generated by `CoefficientArrays` gives you the relationship between the variables in your equations, but since the problem has the form `{v1, ... ,vn}.{A1, ..., An}` (the `Ai`'s are matrices), it is not directly applicable. So, the problem had to be recast so that another function could be used.

Comment: @Daniel, I have updated the quesetion. Would you please complete you have in mind of replacing  y[2, 1] by (-2 + 2 y[1, 1])/(-3) etc. in a programmatic way? Many thanks.